# Hosting with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I've build my application with symfony2 and it works fine in localhost but when I put it online, I can only access some of the area of the application I meant only some of the pages but other pages (which one content many rows of data) generate the folowing error: ContextErrorException in classes.php line 6698:
Warning: file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 35 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space

Is it the server or Symfony ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like application can't write in folders, did you try a clear-cache with the command line tools ? 
What's the production environment ?